# Hangman same character error

Tags: python

```
import timeit

import time

start = timeit.default_timer()

username = input('Enter your username:')

print("Hello,", username, ", do you want to play a game of Hangman?")

question = input("[Y]/[N]?\n")

if question == "Y":
    print("Great, let's start!\n_________")

else:
    print(username, "left the game!")
    time.sleep(2)
    quit()

print('Initializing Game...\nPlease wait...')

time.sleep(5)

game_word = input("Enter the game word:")

list_gw = list(game_word)

word_length = len(list_gw)

print("The word is", word_length, "characters long")

lives = 7
guesses = 0
player_guess = []

while lives > 0:
    letter = input("Enter your guess(lowercase only):\n")
    if letter not in list_gw:
        print("False")
        lives -= 1
        print('You have', lives, 'more lives')
        guesses += 1
    if letter in list_gw:
        print('True')
        print(list_gw.index(letter))
        guesses += 1
        player_guess.insert(list_gw.index(letter), letter)
        if player_guess == list_gw:
            print("You WON!")
            print("It took you only", guesses, "guesses!")
            stop = timeit.default_timer()
            print("This game took", round(stop - start), "seconds")
            quit()
```

I seem to have a problem introducing the concept of the same character appearing in the "game_word". I have trouble finding the right way to approach the situation in which the user-input "letter" appears 2 times or more in the "game_word".
Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `index()` is not a useful function here, as it returns only the index of the **first** occurrence. Find a way to get all indexes of a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.index()` only returns the *first* occurrence of the letter. As @schwobaseggl says in the comments, you need to get *all* the indices of all of the occurrences.

You can do this by using a list comprehension:

```
indices = [i for i in range(len(list_gw)) if list_gw[i] == letter]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that list_gw.index(letter) only returns the first index and not all indexes!

Instead of using index, you could loop through the word, checking each character one by one and update the player_guess accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for this. Create `set` instead of `list`. Like,

```
set_gw = set(game_word)
```

This will give unique items and you can use `set_gw.remove(x)` to remove the item on each iteration.